# How to select columns by data type in Polars?

Tags: dataframe, python-polars

In pandas we have the [`pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) method that selects certain columns depending on the `dtype`. Is there a similar way to do such a thing in Polars?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One can pass a data type to `pl.col`:

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "id": [1, 2, 3],
        "name": ["John", "Jane", "Jake"],
        "else": [10.0, 20.0, 30.0],
    }
)
print(df.select([pl.col(pl.Utf8), pl.col(pl.Int64)]))
```

Output:

```
shape: (3, 2)
┌──────┬─────┐
│ name ┆ id  │
│ ---  ┆ --- │
│ str  ┆ i64 │
╞══════╪═════╡
│ John ┆ 1   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Jane ┆ 2   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Jake ┆ 3   │
└──────┴─────┘
```

Comment: Adding to the discussion, you can use `df.select(pl.col(pl.NUMERIC_DTYPES))` to select all numeric columns. 
I'm looking for the way to select non numeric columns now.

Comment: @Ludecan you can use `all` and `exclude` to select all non numeric columns from a `DataFrame` `df`:
`df.select(pl.all().exclude(pl.NUMERIC_DTYPES))`

Answer (score 6):

Starting from ***Polars 0.18.1*** You can use [`polars.selectors.by_dtype` selector to select all columns matching the given dtypes](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/selectors.html#polars.selectors.by_dtype).

```py
>>> import polars as pl
>>> import polars.selectors as cs
>>> 
>>> df = pl.DataFrame(
...     {
...         "id": [1, 2, 3],
...         "name": ["John", "Jane", "Jake"],
...         "else": [10.0, 20.0, 30.0],
...     }
... )
>>> 
>>> print(df.select(cs.by_dtype(pl.Utf8, pl.Int64)))
shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬──────┐
│ id  ┆ name │
│ --- ┆ ---  │
│ i64 ┆ str  │
╞═════╪══════╡
│ 1   ┆ John │
│ 2   ┆ Jane │
│ 3   ┆ Jake │
└─────┴──────┘
```

To select all non-numeric type columns:

```py
>>> import polars as pl
>>> import polars.selectors as cs
>>> 
>>> df = pl.DataFrame(
...     {
...         "id": [1, 2, 3],
...         "name": ["John", "Jane", "Jake"],
...         "else": [10.0, 20.0, 30.0],
...     }
... )
>>> 
>>> print(df.select(~cs.by_dtype(pl.NUMERIC_DTYPES)))
>>> # OR print(df.select(~cs.numeric()))
shape: (3, 1)
┌──────┐
│ name │
│ ---  │
│ str  │
╞══════╡
│ John │
│ Jane │
│ Jake │
└──────┘
```

Comment: Would it not be enough now-a-days (`0.19.12`) to do just   `df.select(pl.col(pl.NUMERIC_DTYPES))`

Answer (score 0):

When working with groups of datatypes, like numeric dtypes, you can use [polars.selectors](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/selectors.html#polars.selectors.string) datatype groups directly.

Groups include: categorical, date, datetime, float, integer, numeric, string, temporal and time.

```py
# strip whitespace from all string columns
df = df.with_columns(cs.string().str.strip_chars())

# convert all numeric types to float32
df = df.with_columns(cs.numeric().cast(pl.Float32))
```