# Select datetime columns in Polars

Tags: python-polars

In Polars we can select columns by their type -- see e.g. [How to select columns by data type in Polars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72359181/how-to-select-columns-by-data-type-in-polars)

However, I cannot figure out how to select `datetime` columns. From Polars' tutorial we have this example:

```
import polars as pl
import datetime at dt

df_trades = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "time": [
            dt.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 9, 1, 0),
            dt.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 9, 1, 0),
            dt.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 9, 3, 0),
            dt.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 9, 6, 0),
        ],
        "stock": ["A", "B", "B", "C"],
        "trade": [101, 299, 301, 500],
    }
)
```

The column types are printed like this:

```
┌─────────────────────┬───────┬───────┐
│ time                ┆ stock ┆ trade │
│ ---                 ┆ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ str   ┆ i64   │
```

For the `stock` column we can use

```
df_trades.select(pl.col(pl.Utf8))
```

But what is the type for the `time` column? Using `dt.datetime` instead of `pl.Utf8` gives an error:

> TypeError: argument 'name': 'type' object cannot be converted to 'PyString'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select polars columns by datatypes as you did with `pl.Utf8`, but you have to pass a `polars` datatype to make that work, not a python `datetime.datetime` value/object.

Below we select all datetime datatypes that have `"us"` resolution by passing the `pl.Datetime("us")` datatype.

```py
import polars as pl
from datetime import datetime

df_trades = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "time1": [
            datetime(2020, 1, 1, 9, 1, 0),
            datetime(2020, 1, 1, 9, 1, 0),
            datetime(2020, 1, 1, 9, 3, 0),
            datetime(2020, 1, 1, 9, 6, 0),
        ],
        "time2": [
            datetime(2020, 1, 1, 9, 1, 0),
            datetime(2020, 1, 1, 9, 1, 0),
            datetime(2020, 1, 1, 9, 3, 0),
            datetime(2020, 1, 1, 9, 6, 0),
        ],
        "stock": ["A", "B", "B", "C"],
        "trade": [101, 299, 301, 500],
    }
)

df_trades.select(
    pl.col(pl.Datetime("us"))
)
```

```
shape: (4, 2)
┌─────────────────────┬─────────────────────┐
│ time1               ┆ time2               │
│ ---                 ┆ ---                 │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ datetime[μs]        │
╞═════════════════════╪═════════════════════╡
│ 2020-01-01 09:01:00 ┆ 2020-01-01 09:01:00 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2020-01-01 09:01:00 ┆ 2020-01-01 09:01:00 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2020-01-01 09:03:00 ┆ 2020-01-01 09:03:00 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2020-01-01 09:06:00 ┆ 2020-01-01 09:06:00 │
└─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting from ***Polars 0.18.1*** you can use [`polars.selectors.datetime` selector to select only datetime columns](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/selectors.html#polars.selectors.datetime).

```py
>>> import polars as pl
>>> import polars.selectors as cs
>>> import datetime as dt
>>> 
>>> df_trades = pl.DataFrame(
...     {
...         "time": [
...             dt.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 9, 1, 0),
...             dt.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 9, 1, 0),
...             dt.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 9, 3, 0),
...             dt.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 9, 6, 0),
...         ],
...         "stock": ["A", "B", "B", "C"],
...         "trade": [101, 299, 301, 500],
...     }
... )
>>> 
>>> print(df_trades.select(cs.datetime()))
shape: (4, 1)
┌─────────────────────┐
│ time                │
│ ---                 │
│ datetime[μs]        │
╞═════════════════════╡
│ 2020-01-01 09:01:00 │
│ 2020-01-01 09:01:00 │
│ 2020-01-01 09:03:00 │
│ 2020-01-01 09:06:00 │
└─────────────────────┘
```