# How can I strip string columns in a df with mixed datatype in polars?

Tags: python, python-polars

I want to strip a dataframe based on its data type per column. If it is a string column, a strip should be executed. If it is not a string column, it should not be striped. In pandas there is the following approach for this task:

```
df_clean = df_select.copy()
    for col in df_select.columns:
        if df_select[col].dtype == 'object':
            df_clean[col] = df_select[col].str.strip()
```

How can this be executed in polars?

```
import polars as pl
    
df = pl.DataFrame(
        {
            "ID": [1, 1, 1, 1,],
            "A": ["foo ", "ham", "spam ", "egg",],
            "L": ["A54", " A12", "B84", " C12"],
        }
)
```

Comment: `pl.col(pl.Utf8).str.strip()` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72359181/how-to-select-columns-by-data-type-in-polars

Comment: the strip is not the problem. What if I have an other datatyope than string? I need to have an exception like in the example above wit 'object'

Comment: `pl.col(pl.Utf8)` selects only string columns

Comment: but when I select only the string columns I need to append them again to the orignial df because I also need the none string columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a copy, you can directly use `with_columns` on `df_select`:

```
import polars as pl
    
df_select = pl.DataFrame(
        {
            "ID": [1, 1, 1, 1,],
            "A": ["foo ", "ham", "spam ", "egg",],
            "L": ["A54", " A12", "B84", " C12"],
        }
)

df_clean = df_select.with_columns(pl.col(pl.Utf8).str.strip())
```

Output:

```
shape: (4, 3)
┌─────┬──────┬─────┐
│ ID  ┆ A    ┆ L   │
│ --- ┆ ---  ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ str  ┆ str │
╞═════╪══════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ foo  ┆ A54 │
│ 1   ┆ ham  ┆ A12 │
│ 1   ┆ spam ┆ B84 │
│ 1   ┆ egg  ┆ C12 │
└─────┴──────┴─────┘
```