# Polars Python select based on dtype pl.list

Tags: python, python-polars, data-wrangling

Hi I want to select those cols of a polars df that are of the dtype [list](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.List.html).
Selecting by dtypes works ususally fine with `df.select(pl.col(pl.Utf8))`.

However for the type list this does not seem to work...

### MRE

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({"foo": [[c] for c in 
    ["100CT pen", "pencils 250CT", "what 125CT soever", "this is a thing"]]}
)

df
```

**Output:**

```
foo
list[str]
["100CT pen"]
["pencils 250CT"]
["what 125CT soever"]
["this is a thing"]
```

```py
df.select(pl.col(pl.List))
```

**Output:**

```
shape: (0, 0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide the type of the items in the `List` unlike primitive types (where `print(df.select(pl.col(pl.Int64)))` would work in the below example).

```
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "foo": [[c] for c in 
        ["100CT pen", "pencils 250CT", "what 125CT soever", "this is a thing"]],
    "bar": [1, 2, 3, 4]
    }
)
print(df.select(pl.col(pl.List(str))))
```

I can't seem to find anything that's generic across types that the `List` contains. There is a `NESTED_DTYPES` [here](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/blob/e592b160adba3fada2093a735b9b0f6d77767647/py-polars/polars/datatypes/constants.py#L79C1-L79C14) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76628176/4799172) suggests that you might be able to use it in a more "catch-all" manner, but it doesn't seem to work if you want to grab columns that contain a nested type *regardless* of the type of data it contains.

---

Thanks to @jqurious for pointing out that this seems to be a requested feature in an [open ticket](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/9971#issuecomment-1642162835). This has an interesting use-case for me in that, the only reason I've switched dfs back to `pandas` recently is that `polars` refuses to write `List` to CSV so I either filter out *all* such columns by name or, if this is implemented, I could drop them in one go. I didn't create those columns and I don't want them in the output.

Comment: It is on the todo list I believe: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/9971#issuecomment-1642162835 - The information is in `df.schema.items()` by checking the `.base_type()` but that's rather awkward (and only works for the top-level)